# info plist seems outdated and cannot validate App with App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, app-store

I took a project I did recently where the app was universal and I copy-pasted the project. With the copy, I've done a Lite version where I don't support iPad.

I've changed everything I think necessary to make this project as unique, independently that it was a copy from another project: changed the bundleID (matches with the first version on the store), project name, display name, etc. I've removed the iPad storyboard and all the iPad icons. I've also removed the iPad icons from the plist.

Now the App is ready to go and i'm trying to validate it with Apple. Then it gives me the following error:

```
Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Icon-72@2x.png (-19007)
```

but for all the "missing" icons. Before I tried to validate, the debugger said nothing but after the validation attempt, it now give me 6 warnings, which say the same as the error above. One warning per "missing Icon".

I've tried to delete derived data from xcode, clean the project, restart Xcode, etc. But it keeps telling me the same.

Any idea?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: try renaming the icon files. If this fails go to your xcodeproj->show package content (or similar) and delete the xcuserdata folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change from universial to iPhone-only via project interface, the iPad-Icon and the iPad-Storyboard are still in the info.plist.

Just open the info.plist as Propertylist and delete the wrong entries.

Comment: For whatever reason it might be, when I deleted it before it didn't work. I checked it again following your suggestion and they were still there. I deleted them again and it's now ok. Thanks!