# iPad Xib not showing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xib

My root controller for iPhone app is built in code, I im now making app universal and want to link an iPad Xib .  Problem is The iPhone screen still loads instead of the ipad xib

My home controller is named `IChomeContoller`.h and m

So far:

1. Added iPad xib`IChomeContoller~ipad.xib`
2. Set it to my class `IChomeContoller` in IB
3. Connected `new referencing outlet` to the files owner in IB

I also tried it in code in the appdeleage form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753967/universal-app-for-ipad-not-loading-ipad-xib-files) example but still not happening

All my other screens are built with xibs and find the ipad xib no problem

Comment: Look at my answer in this post, i think its the same cause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384968/info-plist-seems-outdated-and-cannot-validate-app-with-app-store/11385246#11385246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted

```
 - (id)init
{

[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ICHomeController" owner:self options:nil];
```

Added in root view controller

Answer (score 1):

Click on your project in Xcode the select your target (should be the bottom one). In there, if it's a universal app, you should see a drop down box for the main screen Xib for both iPhone and iPad. Select a different one for iPad, that should do the trick.

*EDIT*

Alright, try this out:

In your main view controller, the one that gets initialized by your appdelegate, in the init method:

```
- (id)init {

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self = [super initWithNibName:@"<Your iPad xib file here>" bundle:nil];
    }
    else {
        self = [super initWithNibName:@"<Your iPhone xib file here>" bundle:nil];
    }

    if (self) {

        // Everything else you got in your init function
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Sounds promising but I get an error ` this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'`

Comment: Unlink the "view" property in your xib.

Comment: Thanks but still loads iphone screen, I dont have an iphone nib if its relevant and I just commented that out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `IChomeContoller~ipad.xib` was added to your target? In Xcode, select the file in the Project Navigator (on the left), confirm it's checked in the Target Membership section of the File Inspector (on the right).